# Как с помощью Bootstrap 4 сверстать подобное расположение блоков

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, bootstrap4

Учусь верстке на bootstrap 4. Подскажите, как можно расположить блоки таким образом? Или использовать Grid CSS?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит полный макет. Верстаю по методологии BEM

Comment: если не нужно поддерживать IE11 то смело юзайте grid

Comment: Можно полностью макет увидеть? Если это все элементы которые должны так располагаться, то можно обернуть левую часть и правую в `col-6` и флексом выровнять левый блок по центру с помощью `align-items-center`, а правый оставить. И тогда все будет выравниваться как вам и нужно. Но опять же, смотря какой у вас макет, но для решения этой задачи я вижу именно такое решение полностью написанное на `bootstrap4`

Comment: Да, добавтил в ответ

Comment: Сергей, обратите внимание, что в "ответ" добавляются только окончательные способы решения вопроса. Вам же следует дополнить/править свой вопрос. Перенёс в вопрос.

Comment: Как научиться не пихать бутстрап туда, куда не надо...